# javac: invalid flag: getting error when compiling java servlet

Tags: java

I run the command

```
javac -cp C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\lib\servlet-api.jar Demo.java
```

for generating class file

But I am getting an error message:

```
javac: invalid flag: Files\Apache
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a java question, it's a basic "how do I Command Line" question. Spaces separate arguments, so, you have to enclose a path in quotes. That, or, don't put spaces in any of your directory names.